# Параллельная работа скрипта

Tags: предложения, php, mysql

Добрый день, имеется 2 разных скрипта на разных серверах. На каждом сервере база с разными  пользователями. Проблема такая, например, на первом сервере администратор отправляет рассылку. Ту же рассылку хочу отправить и пользователям 2-го сервера. Как решить проблему более правильно не подключаясь к базе 2-го сервера с первого сервера. Интересует не код, а сама идея решения. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: а вы сами себе это как представляете? Вам нужен или один скрипт, который будет цепляться к двум базам, или по скрипту на каждую базу. Во втором случае всё равно откуда-то придётся брать данные для отправки, т.е. прицепиться к другой базе.

Comment: с первого сервера отправьте запрос на запуск скрипта на втором сервере. В итоге на двух серверах будет работать два скрипта.

Comment: думаю так поставить на 2-ой сервер файл который будет получать данные рассылки а потом уже делать свою задачу данную рассылки ему будет передавать 1-ый сервер с помощью curl но я не хочу чтобы первый сервер ждал окончания работы второго сервера, а это думаю так 1-ый сервер запишит рассылку на файл во втором сервере а скрипт во втором сервере будет проверять каждую минуту пока есть файл, просто не знаю правильный ли этот подход?

Comment: Для начала, я бы посоветовал Вам прочитать [это][0]. Потом глядишь и мир понятнее стал бы :-)

[0]: http://www.rusyaz.ru/pr/

Comment: я же вас не учу писать на моем родном языке, пишу так как могу если вы смогли найти ошибки значит поняли что я хотел сказать ну раз поняли лучше бы помогли проблему решить

Comment: Если бы форум был на Вашем родном языке, имели бы право. Почитайте правила для начала. Вот что Вы хотели сказать, я даже не пытался понять. Задавать вопросы таким образом - как минимум не уважение.

Comment: @Royal расставь запятые плиз :(

Answer (score 1):

На втором сервере сделайте API, через которое первый сервер сможет взаимодействовать с ним. Так, например, когда вам нужно будет сделать рассылку, ваш скрипт на первом сервере осуществив свою работу, дергает метод api со второго сервера, к примеру, SendMassMail, в качестве аргументов передает заголовок рассылки, и сам текст рассылки.

Этот пример можно улучшить таким образом, чтобы скрипт на первом сервере не дожидался ответа со второго сервера. Для этого api на втором сервере нужно сделать таким образом, чтобы команды, от которых не требуется немедленного ответа, складывались в очередь заданий. Здесь по идее можно использовать очередь задач какую нибудь, либо навелосипедить самому что нибудь простенькое. Если сделаете так, что дернув api на втором сервере, метод SendMassMail примет у вас аргументы, положит их в очередь задач, и завершит свое выполнение. Такой подход рекомендуется использовать на ресурсах с большим количеством пользователей, или там, где выполнение каких-либо функций занимает непозволительно долгое время.